# How to pass each object in javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am not able to figure out how can I pass a variable to method within a delegate. This is what I am doing,

```
function onGetSubwebsSuccess(sender, args) {
        var webEnumerator = webCollection.getEnumerator();

        while (webEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var web = webEnumerator.get_current();
            this.props = web.get_allProperties();
            context.load(this.props);
            context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, gotProperty), Function.createDelegate(this, failedGettingProperty));
        }
    }

    function gotProperty() {
        var myPropBag = this.props;
        alert(myPropBag.get_fieldValues()["AllowUser"]);
```

How can I pass `web` to `gotProperty` method, is the only choice I have is global variable?

Comment: what framework are you using? asp.net?

Comment: @PatrickEvans sharepoint, but how that would affect passing variable around function :( , thanks

Comment: because `Function.createDelegate` and some of the other objects/functions are not part of normal javascript, least not that i have seen, so needed to know what that was doing. It helps to tag the questions with the framework you are using so others know what to look for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make webEnumerator.moveNext wait until executeQueryAsync query executes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028886/how-to-make-webenumerator-movenext-wait-until-executequeryasync-query-executes)

Comment: I re-wrote my answer to address the `web` variable and the `this` object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in the [executeQueryAsync documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168907%28v=office.15%29.aspx) a way to pass in callback parameters *alongside* the function-name.

`createDelegate` helps you set the context that `this` will point to inside the function delegate.

One workaround, rather than using Function.createDelegate, would be to pass in an anonymous function wrapping a call to gotProperty with the params you want, and using either `call` or `apply` to specify the context, like this:

```
function onGetSubwebsSuccess(sender, args) {
        var webEnumerator = webCollection.getEnumerator();

        while (webEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var web = webEnumerator.get_current();
            this.props = web.get_allProperties();
            context.load(this.props);

            var _this = this;
            context.executeQueryAsync(
                function(){
                    gotProperty.call(_this, web);                       
                },
                function(){
                    failedGettingProperty.call(_this, web);                     
                }
            );          }
    }

    function gotProperty(webParam) {
        //do something with webParam
        var myPropBag = this.props;
        alert(myPropBag.get_fieldValues()["AllowUser"]);
```

Then you can re-write `gotProperty` with the parameters you want to have passed in.
Whatever you do, don't settle for global variables.