# How to make webEnumerator.moveNext wait until executeQueryAsync query executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I want executeQueryAsync to complete before giving back control to webEnumerator.moveNext, anyway ?

```
function onGetSubwebsSuccess(sender, args) {
    var webEnumerator = webCollection.getEnumerator();

    while (webEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        alert("Loop 1");
        web = webEnumerator.get_current();
        this.props = web.get_allProperties();
        context.load(this.props);
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, gotProperty), Function.createDelegate(this, failedGettingProperty));
    }
}

function gotProperty() {
    var myPropBag = this.props;
    alert("Loop 2");
}
```

What's happening now is, I get   alert for "Loop 1" twice and then alert for "Loop 2" when it should be like this,

```
Loop 1
Loop 2
Loop 1
Loop 2
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript I/O is usually non blocking.

`context.executeQueryAsync` returns immediately, so it keeps iterating the original loop. It accepts a callback for when it's done.

What you want is to synchronize it. One concept that allows that is Promises. Since you already tagged this with jQuery, you can use its implementation (or better, a strong one like Bluebird promises) and do something like:

```
// promisify executing the query in a context
function execute(context){
    var d = $.Deferred();
    context.executeQueryAsync(function(v){ return d.resolve(v)},
                              function(e){ return d.reject(v)});
    return d.promise();
}

function onGetSubwebsSuccess(sender, args) {
    var webEnumerator = webCollection.getEnumerator();
    return $.when(1).then(function iterate(){ // start an empty promise
         if(!webEnumerator.moveNext()) return ; // done iterating
         alert("Loop 1"); // console.log is better for this though
         var web = webEnumerator.get_current();
         var props = web.get_allProperties();
         context.load(this.props);
         return execute(context).then(function (result){
              alert("Loop 2");
              alert(result); // do whatever you want with the result of the query
              return iterate(); // loop
         });
    });
}
```

This can get a lot simpler using a stronger promise library like Bluebird which supports this form of iteration using `Promise#reduce` in the first place, but I didn't want to add another library.

The code above will run in sequence, if you want to check when it's done - it returns a promise itself. So you can do `onGetSubwebsSuccess(...).then(function(){ /* done here */ });`

Comment: not sure why, but i got this, Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new c.fn.init(a,b)} has no method 'when'

Answer (score 0):

Since Web properties ([Web.AllProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.allproperties%28v=office.15%29.aspx)) could be requested using a **single** query using the following syntax:

```
clientContext.load(webs,'Include(Url,AllProperties)');
```

there is no need to perform any subsequent asynchronous requests using  `executeQueryAsync` method to load web properties per every web.

The following example demonstrates how to load web properties from sub webs and save them into  `websProps` array:

```
(function(){
  var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var webs = ctx.get_web().get_webs();
  var websProps = {};
  ctx.load(webs,'Include(Url,AllProperties)');  //Note: Explicitly specify which properties to load for Web  
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
       var e = webs.getEnumerator();
       while (e.moveNext()) {
          var web = e.get_current();
          var webUrl = web.get_url();
          var props = web.get_allProperties();
          var propNameValues = props.get_fieldValues();
          //save properties  
          //Note: For demonstration purposes vti_defaultlanguage property is saved, change it to your property name
          websProps[webUrl] = {'DefaultLanguage': propNameValues['vti_defaultlanguage']};
       }
       console.log(JSON.stringify(websProps)); 
    },
    function(sender, args){
        //Handle error
    }
  );
})();
```